# Trying to Toggle A Variable and Update View When Using UI AutoHide

Tags: java, android, view, onclick, toggle

```
    // Set up the user interaction to manually show or hide the system UI.
    contentView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if (TOGGLE_ON_CLICK) {
                mSystemUiHider.toggle();
                ((ZooView)contentView).editmode = mSystemUiHider.isVisible();
            } else {
                mSystemUiHider.show();
            }
        }
    });
```

This is my code, I am trying to update a variable in a custom view (ZooView) to know whether or not the view is in which mode (editmode a custom variable changing OnDraw method primarily)... I tried to invalidate the view when it toggles on click but that's not it, because the logcat showed it wasn't even getting to this function regularly. (only sporadically)

Any ideas?

Comment: Please reword this.  It's impossible to understand.  "update a variable" - what variable?  "the view is in which mode" - which view?  "I tried to invalidate it" - invalidate what?  "getting to this function regularly" - which function?

Comment: The variable editmode in my zooview a custom drawn view, the view is in the edit-mode always(never sets false), tried to invalidate the view to see if it was redrawn, and it isn't getting to the mSystemUiHider.toggle in the posted code always

Answer (score 0):

mSystemUiHider
                .setOnVisibilityChangeListener(new SystemUiHider.OnVisibilityChangeListener() {
                    // Cached values.
                    int mControlsHeight, mControlsWidth;
                    int mShortAnimTime;

```
                @Override
                @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB_MR2)
                public void onVisibilityChange(boolean visible) {

                    ((ZooView)contentView).editmode = visible;
```

putting the change here fixed it totally! :)